# Set the height of each class depending on the size of another class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, each

I have multiple (potentially unlimited) "absolute" classes of DIFFERENT heights, but the below code sets EACH "relative" div to the height of the first absolute element. Each absolute div will be a different height, so I need to loop through and set each relative div to the height of its absolute div correctly.

HTML

```
      <div class="relative">
          <div class="absolute">
           <p>content here, which will be variable, so the heights will not always be the same</p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var current_height = 0;
    $('.absolute').each(function() {
        current_height = $('.absolute').height();
    });
    $('.relative').each(function() {
        $('.relative').height(current_height);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
  #relative {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
  }

 #absolute {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   overflow:hidden;
  }

 #relative,
 #absolute {
    width: 100%;
   max-width: 820px;
  }
```

Comment: Well, your first `.each()` statement isn't terribly useful.  The last object in the `.absolute` list's height is the one that will be used to set the heights of the items in `.relative`.  Are there the same number of divs in each list?

Comment: what is the relation between a relative and absolute div? Please, or you explain this or add html in order to let us understand your question.

Comment: @gaemaf I update my code above.

Comment: @Draco18s - the number of items is dynamic, it could be 3 per page or 100 per page...

Comment: That isn't what I asked, I asked if the total number of `.absolute` items was *the same as* the total number `.relative` items, whether 3 or 300: are there "3 or 300" of both, or is it "3 or 300 of one and different 3 to 300 of the other."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `current_height` variable defined outside the first `.each()` function gets overwritten with each iteration. You need just one loop and can nix the second `.each()` function, like this:

```
$('.absolute').each(function() {
     current_height = $(this).height();
     $(this).parent().height(current_height);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to use the jQuery function height instead of each:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.relative').height(function(index, height) {
    //(this.querySelectorAll('.absolute')[0]).setAttribute('style','height:' + height + 'px');
    // or  in jQuery
    $(this).find('.absolute').css('height',  height + 'px');
  });
});
```

```css
#relative {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#relative,
#absolute {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute">
        <p>content here, which will be variable, so the heights will not always be the same</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute">
        <p>content here, which will be variable, so the heights will not always be the same</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute">
        <p>content here, which will be variable, so the heights will not always be the same</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute">
        <p>content here, which will be variable, so the heights will not always be the same</p>
    </div>
</div>
```